# Host Unknown - XMPP Pidgin

Tags: xmpp, pidgin

I have two machines on my network. I installed ejabberd on one of the machines (Machine A), registered two users there. I have Pidgin running on both machines. I signed into Pidgin to on  machine A, and I was able to sign in. When I tried to sign into the second account on Machine B, I get an error that says Host Unknown. Could someone help me out?

(I checked the ejabber logs and can see machine B trying to access it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. I was putting the IP address of the server in place of domain. So, now I put localhost there, and the IP address in "Connect Server" in the Advanced tab.